# How to set values in cells of row in DatagridView when I change field value?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a `win form application` and i am stuck in a situation with `data grid view`.
what i exactly want to do is, if i enter some bar code then according to the `bar-code` i want to get data and fill them in the the `combo box` of brand name and Item name  and mrp and all.
Which event should i work on and how can i get data and fill in this `data grid-view` row.

[image: Desc]

Comment: I hope my time will be useful result to have new ideas and solutions

Comment: Need more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways, my experience with DataGridView I do as follows.
Suppose you have a model class for your dataGridView

```
 public class MyBarcodeRow
    {
        private String barcode = String.Empty;

        public String Barcode
        {
            get { return barcode; }
            set { 

                barcode = value;
                ////TODO OPERATION ON OTHER FIELD
                //FOR EXAMPLE GET DATA OF QUANTITY FROM DATABASE

                this.Quantity = new Random().Next(Int32.MaxValue);
            }
        }

        private int quantity = 0;

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set { quantity = value; }
        }

        //AND OTHER FIELD

    }
```

In your form drag a BindingSource  and associated it

```
BindingSource.DataSource = MyBarcodeRow
```

Now when you insert the barcode and leave cells you can load other data values.

[image]

From experience I suggest you focus on the events of the BindingSource and the Get / Set methods of the class of model that uses the VIEW.

Then there are also many interesting events in the grid, however, these structures work best when used from this point of view

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource`.
For example you have a class of `Brand`

```
public class Brand
{
    public int32 ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

In the `form` create a list of Brands and fill it with data(from database I assume)

```
List<Brand> _brands;
this.dgvBrandNamesColumn.DataSource = _brands;
this.dgvBrandNamesColumn.DisplayMemeber = "Name";
this.dgvBrandNamesColumn.ValueMemeber = "Name";
```

After adding data to `DataGridView`
`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` will select matched brand name from DataSource(`_brands`)

For more specific help, show code how fill datagridview with data and how/from where you get all brands names